# How to hide the specific tr:nth-child(6) based on the content of a tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I would like to hide with javascript a specific child :

```
#table-detail > tbody > tr:nth-child(10)
```

based on the content of another specific preceding child :

```
#table-detail > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(2)
```

I can hide the child as followed :

```
$('#table-detail > tbody > tr:nth-child(10)').css('display', 'none');
```

but I have no clue how to check the content of the preceding child (if child element

```
#table-detail > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(2)" content == 'Tarte-fine
```

then hide child element X.

Please find hereafter the table :

```
<table id="table-detail" class="table table-striped">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td># Commande</td>
        <td>26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Statut Commande</td>
        <td>Non traitée</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Statut Laboratoire</td>
        <td>Assignée</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nom</td>
        <td>Client Deux</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nature</td>
        <td>Client Mage</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date Retrait</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Catégorie</td>
        <td>Tarte-fine</td> <-CONTENT TO CHECK IN THIS CHILD ELEMENT
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Produit</td>
        <td>Abricots</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td># Personnes</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <- CHILD ELEMENT TO HIDE
        <td>Taille (cm)</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Inscription</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Décoration petites fleurs</td>
        <td>undefined</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Décoration Chocolat et fruits</td>
        <td>undefined</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre de sandwiches</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Poids</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sandwiches 1</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sandwiches 2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sandwiches 3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sandwiches 4</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Couleur du ruban</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Prix</td>
        <td>58</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Weren't you supposed to hide the 10th row if 7th row contains specific text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `:contains()` selector that select element has special text content.

```
$('#table-detail > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(2):contains("Tarte-fine")').css('display', 'none');
```

Also you can simplify the code and use `:eq()` selector instead of `:nth-child`

```
$('#table-detail tr:eq(6) td:eq(1):contains("Tarte-fine")').css('display', 'none');
```

```js
$('#table-detail > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(2):contains("Tarte-fine")').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-detail" class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td># Commande</td>
      <td>26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Statut Commande</td>
      <td>Non traitée</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Statut Laboratoire</td>
      <td>Assignée</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nom</td>
      <td>Client Deux</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nature</td>
      <td>Client Mage</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date Retrait</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Catégorie</td>
      <td>Tarte-fine</td> <!-- CONTENT TO CHECK IN THIS CHILD ELEMENT -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Produit</td>
      <td>Abricots</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td># Personnes</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- CHILD ELEMENT TO HIDE -->
      <td>Taille (cm)</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Inscription</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Décoration petites fleurs</td>
      <td>undefined</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Décoration Chocolat et fruits</td>
      <td>undefined</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre de sandwiches</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Poids</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sandwiches 1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sandwiches 2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sandwiches 3</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sandwiches 4</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Couleur du ruban</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prix</td>
      <td>58</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that `:contain()` return unwanted result in some case, so you can use `.filter()` instead

```
$('#table-detail tr:eq(6) td:eq(1)').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == "Tarte-fine";
}).css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks a lot for this code proposal which works fine, I learned something new with the .filter! Thank you also to saulpaul and Salman.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if that cell contains the specific text using [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and hide that other cell using `hide()`:

```js
$(function() {
  var found = $("#table-detail > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(2):contains(Tarte-fine)").length > 0;
  if (found) {
    $("#table-detail > tbody > tr:nth-child(10)").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table-detail" class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td># Commande</td>
      <td>26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Statut Commande</td>
      <td>Non traitée</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Statut Laboratoire</td>
      <td>Assignée</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nom</td>
      <td>Client Deux</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nature</td>
      <td>Client Mage</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date Retrait</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Catégorie</td>
      <td>Tarte-fine</td>
      <!-- CONTENT TO CHECK IN THIS CHILD ELEMENT -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Produit</td>
      <td>Abricots</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td># Personnes</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- CHILD ELEMENT TO HIDE -->
      <td>Taille (cm)</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Inscription</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Décoration petites fleurs</td>
      <td>undefined</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Décoration Chocolat et fruits</td>
      <td>undefined</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre de sandwiches</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Poids</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sandwiches 1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sandwiches 2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sandwiches 3</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sandwiches 4</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Couleur du ruban</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prix</td>
      <td>58</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative this is the code to do what you need without using jquery.
This is by the way a more solid solution since you don't need to know the numerical order of both of the rows that contain the cell you want to check and the cell you want to hide.

```
const rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
let textToCheck = 'Tarte-fine';
let childTextOfTheElementToHide = 'Taille (cm)';

let check = Object.keys(rows).filter(key => {
 return rows[key].children[1].innerHTML === textToCheck
});

if(check.length > 0){
 let hide = Object.keys(rows).filter(key => {
  return rows[key].children[0].innerHTML === childTextOfTheElementToHide
 }); 
 rows[hide].style.display = 'none';
}
```